# Search string array elements in sqlitedb

Tags: android, oracle, sqlite, search

I have table that contains 7 columns that are ID, NAME, LAT, LON, SPEED and TYPE. The table name is route and by using this code i m able to find the required item from database using the ID field that is provide by search bar against the NAME field but now i want to query similar more items in NAME columns and get there IDs, which i would like to store in cursor. The problem is due to less knowledge about SQL i m unable to write the statement for query.

```
 public Cursor selectByID(long id)
    {
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + K_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }
```

Comment: Please, could you rewrite your question? It's hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if you want to get ID by name:

```
public Cursor selectByName(String name) {
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT " + K_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + NAME + " = " + name, null);
}
```

if you want to get few IDs by few names:

```
 public Cursor selectByNames(String[] names) {
    String where = "WHERE ";
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
        if (i != 0) where += " OR ";
        where += NAME + "='" + names[i] + "'";
    }
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT " + K_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " " + where + " ", null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. It was giving me problem at first but i changed it with "SELECT * FROM " instead of "SELECT " + K_ID + " FROM " in rawQuery.

Comment: if you want to query all columns - use "SELECT * FROM " , but if you need to query just few columns - use exact names of this columns instead of "*" symbol. this will improve performance.